# Android set view position - setY vs setTop

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I was going to move the button's position programmatically. Button is in relative layout. I'd researched and found that we can use `.setY()` or `.setTop()`. It looks like they should work the same.

But in my case, `.setTop()` does not change the position at all and `.setY()` works only. I'm not sure what I did misunderstand but it's very weird for me.

Is there anybody who can explain `setY()` vs `setTop()` correctly?
What is the difference?

This is `layout.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="40dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Actually, setTop() does not work even though I use 1000 or 10000.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main difference between `setY()` and `setTop()` is that `setY()` sets the top offset of the view **relative to the visual area**, whereas `setTop()` sets the top offset of the view **relative to its parent**.

From the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html).

**setY()**

> Sets the visual y position of this view, in pixels. This is equivalent to setting the `translationY` property to be the difference between the `y` value passed in and the current `top` property.

**setTop()**

> Sets the top position of this view relative to its parent.

Comment: thank you for your answer based on Android documentation. Could you provide me an example that shows the difference of these functions exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You can notice that `setTop()` doesn't have effect unlike `setY()`. The reason is that a field `mTop` is being changed by `layout()`. The simplest way to see a changed `mTop` is to set a top margin.